# JQuery Validation - Remote method always check and become true before submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Using jQuery validation plugin, I have been trying to validate and submit my form. `JS` code for this as shown below.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
  "regex",
  function(value, element, regexp) {
    var re = new RegExp(regexp);
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
  },
  "Enter a valid phone number."
);

var phoneNumbers_default = {
  maxlength: 11,
  regex: /^0+\d{2}[ -]\d{7}( x\d{1,6})?$/,
  remote: "./includes/check-duplicate-mobile.php" 
  // remote: {
  //   url: "./includes/check-duplicate-mobile.inc.php",
  //   type: "post"
  // }
};

var phoneNumbers_required = {
  required: true
};

var phoneNumber_message = {
  minlength: "Your mobile number should be at least 11 digits long.",
  maxlength: "Your mobile number cannot be longer than 11 digits.",
  remote: "One active user account already exists for this mobile number. Duplicates are not allowed."
} 

jQuery.extend(phoneNumbers_default,phoneNumbers_required); 

function processForms(el,fileAttached=false) {
  var $el = $('#'+el)
  $el.validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    focusInvalid: false,
    //ignore:  ".ignore",
    ignore:  "",
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },    
      mobileNumber: phoneNumbers_default,
      p_mobile: phoneNumbers_default,
    },

    messages: {
      email: {
        required: "Please provide a valid email.",
        email: "Please provide a valid email."
      },
      mobileNumber:phoneNumber_message,
      p_mobile:phoneNumber_message,
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
      
      var $form = $(form);
      var url = 'add_user_form.php'; 
      var formData = new FormData(form);

      $.ajax({        
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(json) {
          json = jQuery.parseJSON(json)          
          if (json.success) {
            // it worked
          } else {
            // it not worked
          }
        }, 
      });
      return false; 
    }
  })
}
```

Above code works fine for the first submit. I meant it is new form submission. But my problem is when I try to update the existing data using the same form it always checks remote method and become  return ture. That means, if I want to update the existing data, I always have to change the mobile number.

**UPDATE:**
Form markup

```
<form class="mt-2 text-dark-m1" id="addNew_user" method="post" action="" >
      
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right pr-0">
      Email:
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" name="principal_email" class="form-control col-sm-4" value="<?=$p_email?>" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group required row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right pr-0">
      Mobile :
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" name="p_mobile" class="form-control col-sm-4" value="<?=$p_mobile?>" required />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="border-t-1 bgc-secondary-l4 brc-secondary-l2 py-35 mx-n25 mt-5">
    <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-9 text-nowrap flex-align-center">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-bold px-4" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-check mr-1"></i>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Serverside Code:

```
$mobileNumber =  isset($_GET['p_mobile']) ?  $_GET['p_mobile'] : ''; 

if (strlen($mobileNumber) >= 10 && strlen($mobileNumber) <= 12) {
  
  $sql ="SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE mobile = ?";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute([$mobileNumber]);    
  $uid  = $stmt->fetchColumn();

  if ($uid) echo "false"; // it comes to this line
  else echo "true";

} else {
  echo "false";
}
```

Can anybody tell me, how I fix this issue?

Comment: Please, provide us the form markup

Comment: @PauloFernando updated my quesiton with my form markup

Comment: How do we know where the `true` is coming from?  Where is the code at `check-duplicate-mobile.php`?  If you're updating existing data, presumably data already in your database, isn't supposed to be `true` already?  If you want to force it to check again, then set something up that programmatically checks this field... look in docs at `.valid()` method for this.

Comment: @Sparky The problem I have is how the remote method fires when the input does not change. For example, using the edit form, I want to change only the name of the user and submit the form, but when I click the submit button to submit the form, it goes directly to 'check-duplicate-mobile.php' without submitting.

Comment: @Sparky, I updated my serverside code also...

Comment: *" it goes directly to 'check-duplicate-mobile.php' without submitting."* - if that's the case, then it does not return true as your original description states.  If your `check-duplicate-mobile.php` function is returning `false`, then review the server-side logic.  Because it looks like you are trying to validate if the phone is not in the database after you've already inserted the phone number into the database.

Answer (score 1):

What about making this change in the server side? I am still learning php, but i believe you will get the idea.

```
$mobileNumber =  isset($_GET['p_mobile']) ?  $_GET['p_mobile'] : ''; 
$requestUserId =  isset($_GET['user_id']) ?  $_GET['user_id'] : ''; 

if (strlen($mobileNumber) >= 10 && strlen($mobileNumber) <= 12) {
  
  $sql ="SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE mobile = ?";
  
  if (requestUserId) $sql += " AND user_id <> ?"
  
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute([$mobileNumber, $requestUserId]);    
  $uid  = $stmt->fetchColumn();

  if ($uid) echo "false"; // it comes to this line
  else echo "true";

} else {
  echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and appreciate it. But there is a small issue, Think, when updating the records, I need to change the mobile number as well, then according to your logic, remote validation will not work, right?

Comment: Your absolutely right, i edited my answer, check it out ;)

Comment: Yes as you suggest, it is possible in serverside. But I was looking for javascript solution and still I confuse how remote method fires without changing the input.

Comment: The validation fires on input change, but all validations are fired again on form submit, even if nothing has changed. 
Why don't you want to use the server-side solution?
To solve using only javascript, maybe you can bring the current phone number in a hidden field, and use the logic from my first answer, if the phone number was not changed (equal to the hidden field), you remove the remote validation

Comment: `The validation fires on input change, but all validations are fired again on form submit, ` That is the thing I missed.. Thanks for mention it...